# Caching images and displaying

Tags: android, json, imageview, universal-image-loader, lazylist

Hello Am facing a particular problem in which I need to download images and display them onto a `ListView` corresponding to their particular `TextView's`. The code I have is successfully displaying the The `TextView's` I need to display but I don't know how to display all these different images next to my text views in my `ListView`.

After going through many threads in SO. The top answers are to solve this by 
1. Lazy List 
2. Universal Image Loader

I have gone through both the solutions. I downloaded Lazy List codes in which the URL's are hardcoded strings stored in an Array. What I would like to do is create my own Strings dynamically. Store them onto cache and display all the corresponding images.

Here is my code:

```
public class Tools_ListItemActivity extends ListActivity 
{
    private Context context;
    String s;

    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_MDNAME = "mdname";
    private static final String TAG_UTCOST = "utcost";
    private static final String TAG_IIMG= "iimg";
    JSONArray posts = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        s=getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        new ProgressTask(Tools_ListItemActivity.this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

     ListView lv ;



      private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
      private ProgressDialog dialog;

       public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {

       Log.i("1", "Called");
       context = activity;
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
      }

       /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

       /** application context. */
      private Context context;

       protected void onPreExecute() {
       this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
       this.dialog.show();
      }

       @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
       if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
       }
       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
         R.layout.activity_toolsitem, new String[] { TAG_IIMG, TAG_MDNAME, TAG_UTCOST  }, new int[] {
           R.id.imageViewUrl, R.id.mdname, R.id.utcost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        lv = getListView();

      }

       protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(s);


        try {
            posts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String mdname = c.getString(TAG_MDNAME);
            String utcost= c.getString(TAG_UTCOST);
            String iimg=c.getString(TAG_IIMG);

            //Forming the Url of the image to be shown in the list view
            String imageUrl="My_App_URL"+iimg;

/*  try {

              String imageUrl="My_App_URL"+iimg;
              ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewUrl);
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
              imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } */


            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_MDNAME, mdname);
            map.put(TAG_UTCOST, utcost);
            map.put(TAG_IIMG, iimg);



         jsonlist.add(map);
        } }catch (JSONException e) 
        {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;


       }

      }





}
```

Here i have debugged and found out that `imageUrl` gets formed correctly. `Json` only returns the name of the `jpg` so i append that to the URL and Store it in `imageUrl`. The other two textviews are getting properly parsed and displayed. If any one can help me out in displaying the images in the image view too then it would be great. Thanks.

**Update:**
I was able to solve my particular problem with the help of the link shared by Pankaj(https://github.com/AndroidBegin/Android-JSON-Parse-Images-and-Texts-Tutorial) and the concept knowledge shared by Raghunandan down below. Please go through these answers for a detailed explanation as well as implementation of Lazy loading. My apologies for not being able to reward an answer with bounty as i was away for two days.

Comment: what is the problem with universal image loader its working for me in same situation

Comment: i don't know how to use it in my particular case. If u can. Please share the solution using that method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist. might help

Comment: @D'yerMak'er Improve your acceptence rate you should accept Raghunandan answer below , this is what you will need. Also don't waste ur bounty they deserve it.

Comment: @prateek: i haven't checked the answers given below as yet. will check them first. will definitely award the bounty if i find what am looking for. and yes i will do it before the time runs out. Don't worry.

Comment: I don't know that any one of these answers is better than the other. They will all work. Just different ways to do the same thing. If you have a more specific issue with your code rather than a better way generally maybe we can help.

Comment: @Rarw: Raghunandan and pankaj's answers together helped me solve my problem. dynamic forming of urls was a problem while json parsing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lazy loading using Universal Imageloader. Replace the hardcoded urls with url of images.

Modify the below according to your requirements

[What's LazyList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist). Check this link for details.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private String[] mStrings={
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/605536070/twitterProfilePhoto.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small.jpg",
            "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
            "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png"
    };

    ListView lv;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(new LazyAdapter(this,mStrings));
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="2.0"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private String data[];
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "MyFolderCache");

        // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
              // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
             .discCacheExtraOptions(1024, 1024, CompressFormat.PNG, 100)
             .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
             .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
             .enableLogging()
             .build();
        // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
        imageLoader.init(config);
        //imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(a));
        // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
             .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
             .cacheInMemory()
             .cacheOnDisc()
             .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
             .build();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();;
        if(convertView==null)
        {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);   
            vh.iv=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivv); 
            vh.pb= (ProgressBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.pb); 
            vh.tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            vh.tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }
        vh.tv.setText("Image in postion =");
        vh.tv1.setText(""+position);
        display(vh.iv, data[position], vh.pb);
        //imageLoader.displayImage(data.get(position).toString(), image,options);
        return vi;
    }

    public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
    {
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView iv;
        TextView tv,tv1;
        ProgressBar pb;
    }
}
```

### row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[image]

Comment: @Rarw if that was the case i guess he would not have asked the question anyway

Comment: @Raghunandan:apologies for a late reply. My issue was as i was dealing with many url strings coming from the server as json. I had to form those url's and then carry on with the downloading task. the solution you have given works perfectly for hardcoded string urls. but not so in my case. after trying to figure out different ways i posted this question. Now the solution suggested by Pankaj sharma down below helped me in forming my answer. so am going to accept that as an answer. but thanks for explaining the concept of lazy list and classes required to make lazy list work. thanks a lot.

Comment: @D'yerMak'er you need to parse json and store it in a list and provide the url in custom adapter. its simple but you need to modify the same. the above works in both hardcoded and urls that you get from parsing json. i have tested both and used the same in my application

Comment: @Raghunandan: yes it does. and yes now i have done the same using the answer you have shared and this link( https://github.com/AndroidBegin/Android-JSON-Parse-Images-and-Texts-Tutorial ) pankaj shared. thanks for sharing the detailed solution and also sharing the knowledge of the concept of lazy loading.

Comment: @D'yerMak'er well i leave it to you to decide which answer helped the most. but i can say the above works fine. all you need to do is provide the urls afer parsing json.

Comment: @Raghunandan: on second thought your answer is more complete for people who may want the solution to this in the future so accepted your answer. Thanks a lot for the reply. it helped a great deal.

Comment: how about if the images are inside the device folder locally ?

Comment: Well if the Image is already loaded in listview then how will one be able to zoom that image?
What will be the full url stored inside the system?
I don't want to re download that image from internet to zoom in, in next activity?

Comment: @DurgeshKumar i have not universal Image Loader for a long time. I have been using glide or picasso. Pls check their documentation. If not you can create your own cache and get the path of the image and then zoom the image using matrix. Besides if you already have the image i don't think any image downloader will download the image again. All you need to do is scale the image

Comment: I used picasso and it worked nicely i.e.
` Picasso.with(ctx).load( image)
                .fit().into((ImageView) image);`

Comment: @DurgeshKumar yes you can use picasso or glide and use transformation if needed

Answer (score 3):

Please try this with universal image loader

```
public class DetailsListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry>{
    private Context context;
    private List<Entry> detailList;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public DetailsListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<Entry> detailList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,detailList);
        this.detailList = detailList;
        this.context = context;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.blankimage)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.blankimage)
        .resetViewBeforeLoading()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
        .build();
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        private TextView popupDetails;
        private TextView pubDate;
        private ImageView image;
        private ProgressBar progress;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.details_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.popupDetails=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.detailHeading);
            holder.pubDate = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pubDate);
            holder.image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.listImg);
            holder.progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        Entry value = detailList.get(position);
        holder.popupDetails.setText(value.getTitle());
        holder.pubDate.setText(value.getPubDate());
        String url = value.getImageLink();
        try {
            if(url.length() > 5) {
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadImage(holder.image,url,holder.progress);
            } else {
                if(url.equals("NO")) {
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.show(e);
        }
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        return v;

    }
    public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String loadURL,final ProgressBar progress) {
        imageLoader.displayImage(loadURL, imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) {
                case IO_ERROR:
                    message = "Input/Output error";
                    break;
                case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                    message = "Out Of Memory error";
                    break;
                case NETWORK_DENIED:
                    message = "Downloads are denied";
                    break;
                case UNSUPPORTED_URI_SCHEME:
                    message = "Unsupported URI scheme";
                    break;
                case UNKNOWN:
                    message = "Unknown error";
                    break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(final String imageUri, View view, final Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }  
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this: please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861807/is-the-listview-recycling-early-or-is-universal-imageloader-canceling-in-error/16972610#16972610
The listView will recycle the very first view before the image can load and so the load will be canceled, and the image on the first item will not display.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I load and cache images in a `ListView` that creates a contact list for the user. So imagine profile picture on the left, some text views on the right (which sounds close to the problem you're dealing with. Ignore the ugly debug tags and probably poor formatting (sorry). I guess this is kind of like LazyList but here's a detailed explanation in case anyone was confused.

**Step 1: Set Up Your Cache**

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> memoryCache;
private HashMap<String, String> idPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

In my approach I use an `LruCache` and a `HashMap` to track which user's images I've downloaded. You'll see how its implemented later but the idea is to avoid downloading stuff from the server unless you have to. Then in your `onCreate()` or some related method, initialize your cache.

```
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    memoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize)  {
        @Override 
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap){
            return (bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight()) / 1024; //don't use getByteCount for API < 12
        }
    };
```

My next step is to add the default "empty image" bitmap to the cache in case I reach an entry that does not have a picture associated with it. That way I only have to process and add this bitmap once

```
Bitmap defaultPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.default_user_picture);
    addBitmapToMemoryCache("default", defaultPicture);
```

Then its time to get the data you need for the list!

**Step 2: Get The Data**

```
private class GetPeopleData extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(JSONArray...lists) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
        ResponseHandler <String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        if(DEBUG) Log.d("GET PEOPLE DATA TASK", lists[0].length() + " users");
        getUsers(lists[0], httpClient, httpPost, responseHandler);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        updateUserListView();
    }

}
```

Here's a borring `AsyncTask` that takes a `JSONArray` of user data as an argument. I left out that part because it's pretty much just a basic HTTP download that doesn't need explanation. The getUsers method is where I start to put together what will be added to my `ListView`. What I do next is process the JSON downloaded from the server to create user objects that will be added it to a list of users that will be displayed.

```
private void getUsers(JSONArray userArray, HttpClient httpClient, HttpPost httpPost, ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler){
    if(DEBUG) Log.d("USERS ARRAY", userArray.length() + " users");
    try{

        users = new ArrayList<User>();
        if(DEBUG) Log.d("User Array -START", "" + users.size());
        //Go through userArray and get information needed for list
        for(int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++){
            User u = new User();
            if(DEBUG) Log.d("User Array - ADD USER", "" + users.size());
            String profileId = userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("profileid");
            u.setId(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            u.setDisplayName(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("displayname"));
            u.setStatus(userArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("status"));

            //check HashMap for sender/profileid pair
            if(idPairs.containsKey(profileId)){
                if(DEBUG) Log.d("idPairs", "User in HashMap");
                profileId = idPairs.get(profileId);
            } else {
                if(DEBUG) Log.d("idPairs", "User not in HashMap. Add profileId");
                idPairs.put("profileId", profileId);
            }
            u.setProfilePicture(getProfilePictureFromCache(profileId, httpClient, httpPost, responseHandler)); //check cache for image
            users.add(u);
            if(DEBUG) Log.d("User info", u.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I associate the picture with the user object that will eventually be displayed. I figure this isn't a total waste of time since the image is pulled from the bitmap cache

```
private Bitmap getProfilePictureFromCache(String profileId, HttpClient httpClient, HttpPost httpPost, ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler){
    Bitmap defaultPicture = getBitmapFromMemCache("default");
    Bitmap profilePicture = getBitmapFromMemCache(profileId);
    if(profilePicture != null){
        return profilePicture;
    } else {        
        String pictureString = getProfilePic(profileId, httpClient, httpPost, responseHandler);
        if(!pictureString.isEmpty()){       
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(pictureString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            profilePicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(profileId, profilePicture);
            if(DEBUG) Log.d("MEMCACHE", "Download and store picture for " + profileId);
            return profilePicture;
        } else if (defaultPicture != null && pictureString.equals(null)) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.d("MEMCACHE", "Load default picture");
            return defaultPicture;
        }
    }
    return defaultPicture;
}
```

If a picture exists in the cache it is returned, if not it is downloaded. For me, displaying users, each picture is cached according to userid so even if someone were to appear more than once in the list, there would only be one picture stored in the cache for that user.

```
ImageView profile_picture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
if(profile_picture != null){
                profile_picture.setImageBitmap(u.getProfilePicture());
            }
```

The only thing left to do is find the `ImageView` in your adapter and set that view to the picture you associated with the object in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something easy to use? With take care of caching files, deleting the cache, release when the memory is at border line?

Try LazyList, check it out:

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/LazyList

As it is explained, you only need to create the Singleton in your Application class or any other Activity or Fragment:

```
//To use the default external folder, this folder will be deleted when the app no longe exists.
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext());
//Or to use another folder, use...
//ImageLoader.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), "MyExternalFolder");
```

Then in your view that has the ImageView to display de Image you need to implement ImageProcessingCallback interface:

```
public class MyItemView extends LinearLayout implements ImageProcessingCallback {
...
//Do what you need in methods onImagePreProcessing() and onImageProcessing(Bitmap     bitmap)
...
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(data[position], myView);
```

Finally you need to add this permission in your androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And that's it. Then you have methods to clear the cache for ram cache or disk cache or both.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about storing the images, as my app uses images from the APK.
However I believe for displaying those images you want a custom Arrayadapter.

This inflates a layout for each item and places it in a list. This layout is defined by and XML layout you create and specify in its construction. You should try extending whatever adapter you currently use for your list view with a custom one that sets the image view according to the item.

I do this with ImageView.setImageResource(resource ID); But your mileage may vary. I have my images in the APK not sure how to display them from an external source