# outofmemoryerror at android.graphics.bitmapfactory.nativedecodestream

Tags: android

I want to show product image. Each products have 4 images. When I show image in ImageView then I got out of memory.

This is my code:

```
public class ImagesActivity extends Activity  {
private String styleCode,styleName;
private String strExecutive;
private Uri[] mUrls;  
String[] mFiles=null;  
private  Gallery g;
private ImageView picture;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)  {  
    super.onCreate(icicle);  
    setContentView(R.layout.image_view); 

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    styleCode =  b.getString("styleCode");
    styleName =b.getString("styleCode");

    setTitle(styleName);

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myLogedPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    strExecutive = myPrefs.getString("Executive", "");

    picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

    Button picCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.picCancel);
    picCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
            bundle.putString("Activity", "ImagesActivity");
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            finish();
        }
    });

    String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+strExecutive+"/"+styleCode+"/";
    File filePath = new File(folderPath);
    File[] imagelist = filePath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  {  
            return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png")));
        }  
    });  
    mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];  

    for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)  
    {  
        mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();  
    }  
    mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];  

    for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)  
    {  
        mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);     
    }     

    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);  
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  
    g.setFadingEdgeLength(40); 



    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(arg1.getContext()," Image is available to this style"  + arg2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getLargeImage(arg2);
        }
    });
}  


public void getLargeImage(int position) {
    Uri pickedUri =mUrls[position];
    Bitmap pic = null;
    String imgPath = "";
    String[] medData = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor picCursor = managedQuery(pickedUri, medData, null, null, null);
    if(picCursor!=null)
    {
        int index = picCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        picCursor.moveToFirst();
        imgPath = picCursor.getString(index);
    }
    else
        imgPath = pickedUri.getPath();
        if(pickedUri!=null) {

            int targetWidth = 600;
            int targetHeight = 400;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bmpOptions);

            int currHeight = bmpOptions.outHeight;
            int currWidth = bmpOptions.outWidth;
            int sampleSize = 1;
            if (currHeight>targetHeight || currWidth>targetWidth) 
            {
                if (currWidth>currHeight)
                    sampleSize = Math.round((float)currHeight/(float)targetHeight);
                else 
                    sampleSize = Math.round((float)currWidth/(float)targetWidth);
            }
            bmpOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            bmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, bmpOptions);
            Drawable toRecycle= picture.getDrawable();
            if (toRecycle != null) {
                ((BitmapDrawable)picture.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
            }
            picture.setImageBitmap(pic);
            picture.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
       }

}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{  
    int mGalleryItemBackground;  
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)  {     
        mContext = c;    

        TypedArray styleAttrs = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.PicGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = styleAttrs.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.PicGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        styleAttrs.recycle();
    }  
    public int getCount(){  
        return mUrls.length;  
    }  
    public Object getItem(int position){  
        return position;  
    }  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){  
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);  
        Drawable toRecycle= i.getDrawable();
        if (toRecycle != null) {
            ((BitmapDrawable)i.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
        }

        i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);  
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(260, 210));  
        return i;  
    }     
    private Context mContext;  
    }
```

Error say :

```
     06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:582)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:380)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:413)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:880)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:569)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:340)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at xont.sdfd.controller.sales.ImagesActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(ImagesActivity.java:225)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2240)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1092)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-13 17:51:26.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27358):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tested my application samsung galaxy 2 7.0 tab.

Please tell me , in my code what is an issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020854/out-of-memory-exception-while-implementing-image-gallery/17021099#17021099

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765899/out-of-memory-error-with-bitmap/16766123#16766123. check this. if you have a large image you need to scale down the image. and this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: consider using lazy laoding using lazy list of universal image loader. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285

Answer (score 1):

You are performing the sampling only once. That could be the reason you are getting OOM.

Try this:

```
   if (currHeight>targetHeight || currWidth>targetWidth) 
        {
            if (currWidth>currHeight)
                sampleSize = Math.round((float)currHeight/(float)targetHeight);
            else 
                sampleSize = Math.round((float)currWidth/(float)targetWidth);
        }

        final float totalPixels = currWidth * currHeight;
        // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels, sample down further

        final float totalReqPixelsCap = targetWidth * targetHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){  
    ImageView i = convertView;  
    Drawable toRecycle= i.getDrawable();
    if (toRecycle != null) {
        ((BitmapDrawable)i.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
    }

    i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);  
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(260, 210));  
    return i;  
}
```

Also, try [increasing your VM heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application) to allow your sandboxed environment to allocate more memory.

Comment: already i wrote in my code also & android:largeHeap="true" in manifeast file also

Comment: if you use  android:largeHeap="true" heap is large..larger the heap more frequent garbabge collection more frequent pause times. so you should be careful in using it.