# Out of memory Error while displaying images

Tags: android

I am getting images from json as a list view.

All the text from json was displaying fine but image cannot be display. In logcat, it showing `Out of memory error`

I think there's a problem in image loading and memory cache.

Below is my Image loader and Memory cache class and logcat.

ImageLoader.java

```
   public class ImageLoader {

     MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
     FileCache fileCache;
     private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

     ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread

     Handler handler = new Handler();

       public ImageLoader(Context context) {
       fileCache = new FileCache(context);
       executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
      }

     final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_image;

     public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
      imageViews.put(imageView, url);
      Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
      if (bitmap != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       else {
             queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
      }
   }

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // Download Images from the Internet
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        System.out.println("OutOfMemoryError " +ex);

        return null;
    }
}

// Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        // Recommended Size 512
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
}



MemoryCache.java


     public class MemoryCache {

private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

// Last argument true for LRU ordering
private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));

// Current allocated size
private long size = 0;

// Max memory in bytes
private long limit = 1000000;

public MemoryCache() {
    // Use 25% of available heap size
    setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
}

public void setLimit(long new_limit) {
    limit = new_limit;
    Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to " + limit / 1024. / 1024. + "MB");
}

public Bitmap get(String id) {
    try {
        if (!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        return cache.get(id);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        if (cache.containsKey(id))
            size -= getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
        cache.put(id, bitmap);
        size += getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
        checkSize();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkSize() {
    Log.i(TAG, "cache size=" + size + " length=" + cache.size());
    if (size > limit) {
        // Least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
        Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter = cache.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iter.next();
            size -= getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
            iter.remove();
            if (size <= limit)
                break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size " + cache.size());
    }
}

public void clear() {
    try {
        cache.clear();
        size = 0;
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap == null)
        return 0;
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
}
```

Here my logcat :

```
  06-11 11:22:27.910: D/dalvikvm(526): GC freed 1102 objects / 244576 bytes in 174ms
  06-11 11:25:55.619: D/AndroidRuntime(541): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  06-11 11:25:55.629: D/AndroidRuntime(541): CheckJNI is ON
  06-11 11:25:55.909: D/AndroidRuntime(541): --- registering native functions ---
  06-11 11:25:56.390: D/ddm-heap(541): Got feature list request
  06-11 11:25:56.949: D/PackageParser(63): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl38984.tmp
  06-11 11:25:57.320: I/PackageManager(63): Removing non-system                                 package:com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial
  06-11 11:25:57.329: D/PackageManager(63): Removing package com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial
  06-11 11:25:57.329: D/PackageManager(63):   Activities:     com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.MainActivity com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.SingleItemView
  06-11 11:25:57.480: D/PackageManager(63): Scanning package com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial
  06-11 11:25:57.490: I/PackageManager(63): /data/app/vmdl38984.tmp changed; unpacking
  06-11 11:25:57.511: D/installd(31): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/vmdl38984.tmp' ---
  06-11 11:25:59.039: D/dalvikvm(547): DexOpt: load 200ms, verify 799ms, opt 32ms
  06-11 11:25:59.079: D/installd(31): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/vmdl38984.tmp' (success) ---
  06-11 11:25:59.091: D/PackageManager(63):   Activities:  com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.MainActivity com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.SingleItemView
  06-11 11:25:59.100: D/ActivityManager(63): Uninstalling process   com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial
  06-11 11:25:59.100: D/ActivityManager(63): Force removing process ProcessRecord{43db9e78   526:com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/10026} (com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/10026)
  06-11 11:25:59.100: I/Process(63): Sending signal. PID: 526 SIG: 9
  06-11 11:25:59.159: D/ActivityManager(63): Received spurious death notification for thread  android.os.BinderProxy@43cc72e0
  06-11 11:25:59.339: I/installd(31): move /data/dalvik- cache/data@app@vmdl38984.tmp@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.apk@classes.dex
  06-11 11:25:59.350: D/PackageManager(63): New package installed in /data/app/com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.apk
  06-11 11:25:59.549: D/AndroidRuntime(541): Shutting down VM
  06-11 11:25:59.549: D/dalvikvm(541): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
  06-11 11:25:59.560: D/dalvikvm(541): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
  06-11 11:25:59.570: D/dalvikvm(541): HeapWorker thread shutting down
  06-11 11:25:59.570: D/dalvikvm(541): HeapWorker thread has shut down
  06-11 11:25:59.570: D/jdwp(541): JDWP shutting down net...
  06-11 11:25:59.570: I/dalvikvm(541): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
  06-11 11:25:59.570: D/dalvikvm(541): VM cleaning up
  06-11 11:25:59.610: D/ActivityManager(63): Uninstalling process         com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial
  06-11 11:25:59.610: E/AndroidRuntime(541): ERROR: thread attach failed
  06-11 11:25:59.624: D/dalvikvm(541): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 623012 of 5242880 (11%)
  06-11 11:26:00.270: D/dalvikvm(63): GC freed 7834 objects / 550336 bytes in 376ms
  06-11 11:26:00.299: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number  0x7f0700e5
  06-11 11:26:00.329: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031
  06-11 11:26:00.329: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030
  06-11 11:26:00.329: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000
  06-11 11:26:00.409: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001
  06-11 11:26:00.499: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060000
  06-11 11:26:00.810: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5
  06-11 11:26:00.820: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031
   06-11 11:26:00.820: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030
  06-11 11:26:00.820: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000
  06-11 11:26:00.860: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001
  06-11 11:26:00.869: D/dalvikvm(143): GC freed 183 objects / 8056 bytes in 569ms
  06-11 11:26:00.869: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060000
  06-11 11:26:01.430: D/AndroidRuntime(552): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  06-11 11:26:01.459: D/AndroidRuntime(552): CheckJNI is ON
  06-11 11:26:01.879: D/AndroidRuntime(552): --- registering native functions ---
  06-11 11:26:02.409: D/ddm-heap(552): Got feature list request
  06-11 11:26:02.929: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/.MainActivity }
  06-11 11:26:03.030: D/AndroidRuntime(552): Shutting down VM
  06-11 11:26:03.030: D/dalvikvm(552): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
  06-11 11:26:03.039: D/dalvikvm(552): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
  06-11 11:26:03.039: D/dalvikvm(552): HeapWorker thread shutting down
  06-11 11:26:03.050: D/dalvikvm(552): HeapWorker thread has shut down
  06-11 11:26:03.050: D/jdwp(552): JDWP shutting down net...
  06-11 11:26:03.050: I/dalvikvm(552): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
  06-11 11:26:03.050: D/dalvikvm(552): VM cleaning up
  06-11 11:26:03.100: I/ActivityManager(63): Start proc com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial for activity com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/.MainActivity: pid=559 uid=10026 gids={3003, 1015}
  06-11 11:26:03.110: E/AndroidRuntime(552): ERROR: thread attach failed
  06-11 11:26:03.160: D/dalvikvm(552): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 638596 of 5242880 (12%)
  06-11 11:26:03.440: D/ddm-heap(559): Got feature list request
  06-11 11:26:03.480: D/dalvikvm(29): GC freed 310 objects / 12008 bytes in 351ms
  06-11 11:26:04.049: D/dalvikvm(29): GC freed 52 objects / 2296 bytes in 514ms
  06-11 11:26:04.219: D/dalvikvm(29): GC freed 2 objects / 56 bytes in 159ms
  06-11 11:26:04.669: I/ActivityManager(63): Displayed activity com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/.MainActivity: 1662 ms (total 1662 ms)
  06-11 11:26:06.240: D/dalvikvm(559): GC freed 3046 objects / 226432 bytes in 104ms
  06-11 11:26:06.300: I/MemoryCache(559): MemoryCache will use up to 4.0MB
  06-11 11:26:06.990: W/System.err(559): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.1.52/projects/konnectplus_new/includes/marketing/comingsoon-medium.jpg
  06-11 11:26:06.999: W/System.err(559):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
  06-11 11:26:07.009: W/System.err(559):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
  06-11 11:26:07.009: W/System.err(559):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:67)
  06-11 11:26:07.009: W/System.err(559):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:57)
  06-11 11:26:07.020: W/System.err(559):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:151)
  06-11 11:26:07.020: W/System.err(559):    at  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
  06-11 11:26:07.020: W/System.err(559):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   06-11 11:26:07.020: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
  06-11 11:26:07.020: W/System.err(559):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
  06-11 11:26:07.030: W/System.err(559):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  06-11 11:26:07.030: W/System.err(559):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
  06-11 11:26:07.039: W/System.err(559): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.1.52/projects/konnectplus_new/includes/marketing/rajini-medium.jpg
  06-11 11:26:07.039: W/System.err(559):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
  06-11 11:26:07.039: W/System.err(559):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
  06-11 11:26:07.039: W/System.err(559):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:67)
  06-11 11:26:07.039: W/System.err(559):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:57)
  06-11 11:26:07.039: W/System.err(559):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:151)
  06-11 11:26:07.049: W/System.err(559):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
  06-11 11:26:07.049: W/System.err(559):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
  06-11 11:26:07.049: I/System.out(559): **OutOfMemoryError java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.*.***/projects/*********_new/includes/marketing/comingsoon-medium.jpg**
   06-11 11:26:07.060: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   06-11 11:26:07.060: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
   06-11 11:26:07.060: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
   06-11 11:26:07.070: I/MemoryCache(559): cache size=0 length=1
   06-11 11:26:07.070: W/System.err(559):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
   06-11 11:26:07.080: W/System.err(559): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.1.52/projects/konnectplus_new/includes/marketing/BlastfromPast-medium.jpg
   06-11 11:26:07.080: W/System.err(559):   at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
   06-11 11:26:07.080: W/System.err(559):   at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
   06-11 11:26:07.080: W/System.err(559):   at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:67)
   06-11 11:26:07.080: W/System.err(559):   at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:57)
   06-11 11:26:07.090: W/System.err(559):   at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:151)
   06-11 11:26:07.090: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
   06-11 11:26:07.090: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   06-11 11:26:07.090: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   06-11 11:26:07.099: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
   06-11 11:26:07.099: W/System.err(559):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
   06-11 11:26:07.099: W/System.err(559):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
   06-11 11:26:07.099: I/System.out(559): **OutOfMemoryError java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.*.**/projects/******88_new/includes/marketing/BlastfromPast-medium.jpg**
   06-11 11:26:07.111: I/MemoryCache(559): cache size=0 length=2
   06-11 11:26:07.111: I/System.out(559): **OutOfMemoryError java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.*.**/projects/******8_new/includes/marketing/rajini-medium.jpg**
   06-11 11:26:07.111: I/MemoryCache(559): cache size=0 length=3
   **06-11 11:26:07.120: W/System.err(559): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.*.**/projects/******_new/includes/marketing/oneticketonemovie-medium.jpg**
   06-11 11:26:07.120: W/System.err(559):   at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
   06-11 11:26:07.143: W/System.err(559):   at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
   06-11 11:26:07.143: W/System.err(559):   at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:67)
   06-11 11:26:07.143: W/System.err(559):   at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:57)
    06-11 11:26:07.143: W/System.err(559):  at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:151)
    06-11 11:26:07.143: W/System.err(559):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    06-11 11:26:07.150: W/System.err(559):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    06-11 11:26:07.150: W/System.err(559):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    06-11 11:26:07.150: W/System.err(559):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    06-11 11:26:07.150: W/System.err(559):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    06-11 11:26:07.150: W/System.err(559):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
    06-11 11:26:07.150: I/System.out(559): **OutOfMemoryError java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.*.**/projects/******_new/includes/marketing/oneticketonemovie-medium.jpg**
   06-11 11:26:07.163: I/MemoryCache(559): cache size=0 length=4
   06-11 11:26:09.959: D/dalvikvm(280): GC freed 44 objects / 2112 bytes in 156ms
   06-11 11:26:15.080: D/dalvikvm(143): GC freed 2205 objects / 129320 bytes in 204ms
   06-11 11:28:14.110: W/KeyCharacterMap(559): No keyboard for id 0
   06-11 11:28:14.110: W/KeyCharacterMap(559): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
   06-11 11:28:14.300: W/InputManagerService(63): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43d098f0 (uid=10026 pid=559)
   06-11 11:28:14.459: W/KeyCharacterMap(143): No keyboard for id 0
   06-11 11:28:14.459: W/KeyCharacterMap(143): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
   06-11 11:28:19.940: D/dalvikvm(559): GC freed 2515 objects / 165976 bytes in 188ms
```

Error :

```
06-11 11:26:07.150: I/System.out(559): **OutOfMemoryError java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.*.**/projects/******_new/includes/marketing/oneticketonemovie-medium.jpg**
```

Comment: You are right, posting the code is not relevant, we will try to guess ;-)

Comment: It says `java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found`.  Perhaps you need `http://` in the url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285. use Universal Image Loader

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an Out of Memory error.  This is simply a `java.net.MalformedURLException`.  The reason you are seeing the message OutOfMemory is from the code that catches the exception, where you write:

```
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
        memoryCache.clear();
    System.out.println("OutOfMemoryError " +ex); // <--- RIGHT HERE

    return null;
}
```

The real problem you are facing is the fact that the URL constructor is throwing the `java.net.MalformedURLException` because you haven't included the protocol in the URL.

Comment: Your url is `192.168.1.52/projects/konnectplus_new/includes/marketing/comingsoon-medium.jpg` which is an ip address, so I would guess it is http or https.  Check the URL docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) for supported protocols in case it is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading full sized images, you need to scale it down. There is the article about this [there](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need the clear the cache. Images downloaded should be stored in cache try this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

I also suffer from the problem. Try below the code in your main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

    dbup.deletedata();
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout));
    System.gc();
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if ((view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```