# How to show image from the url in listview using simple adapter in android?

Tags: android, image, url

Can any one tell me how to show image from the url in list-view in android using Simple adapter.

Suggestions please
Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285. check this using universal image loader

Comment: Display what thing you attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Hey it is too easy to implement using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). This is the library for the Displaying the image in ListView, Gridview and any other one in which you are adapting the views.

You can also use lazy loading of images.[Here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) is the code.

[image]