# Using Universal ImageLoader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

If I write this code:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

I get this error:

```
06-16 16:04:23.729: E/AndroidRuntime(13889): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader
```

I've added `universal-image-loader-1.8.4.jar` in `lib` and imported `com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader`

How can I use the ImageLoader class?

Comment: if your looking for code snippets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285 this can help

Comment: add compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5' to your gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jar to the **libs** folder and not to the **lib**.
If you add it manually to the **lib** folder, then go to:
 -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export and there select the jar

Comment: Yes, l do it before ask the qquestion

Comment: If you use Eclipse+ADT plugin then you need only put jat into `libs` folder. **Don't reference** jar from `Java Build Path -> ...` Delete reference from there if any.