# Custom GridView causes out of memory error while loading lots of images

Tags: android, gridview, out-of-memory

I have a custom layout for gridview. Each raw of gridview contains a progressbar, two imageviews and two text views. The image size are thumbnail sizes. While i have to load lots of bitmaps eg:- 500 images , which causes out of memory error. the images are first time loading from Internet and then which is stored in SD card and the next time when you loading the gridview which is loading from SD card. How to overcome this issue. I have found lots of answers to overcome out of memory if the gridview is inflated with single imageview. Please suggest me how to overcome this issue while using custom layout.Let me know if you know any example projects that handle this out of memory error in gridview while inflating custom layout in gridview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285. try lazy loading using universal image loader.

Answer (score 2):

> It would be best to create a class that extends Application . This
>   application class will give you onlowmemory() callback whenever
>   application goes low memory. on there you can write
>
> public void onLowmemory() {
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); }
>
> which will invoke system GC method. Upon executing garbage collector
>   android will garbage all unused objects.
>
> There is another way to solve this problem. In animation you can call
>   Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); to invoke garbage collector. also in
>   activity onDestroy() method u can call Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
>
> so your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

try this code set in image for gridview  [out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;//you set size qulity for image(2,3,,4,5,6,7,8 etc..) 
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

set this bitmap in your imageview

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.
The OutOfMemoryError is usually caused by
The first approach is to

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(srcImg);
```

Since images are transformed into bitmap before displaying, lots of big bitmap usually cause the error.

To overcome this, I added the following function

```
public static Bitmap decodeWithBounds(String srcImg, int bounds) {
    if (bounds > 0){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(srcImg, options);

        if (options.outHeight > bounds || options.outWidth > bounds){
            options.inSampleSize = Math.max(options.outHeight/bounds, options.outWidth/bounds);
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(srcImg, options);
    } else {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(srcImg);
    }
}
```

I use this function to decode bitmap, with bounds = grid size.

This solved most problem.

For very low end device, add a try{} catch (OutOfMemoryError e){} ...

Answer (score 0):

Solve the out of memory exception issue with this code

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
if (bitmap != null) {
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
}
```