# How Replace String[] Constants with Strings[] from SQLITE

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I a currently studying the Universal-Image-Loader implementing the Gridview of the images.  I was able to run the project using the predefined image paths. Please help find a better solution for this.

Basing from [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/Constants.java):

The problem is I want to use the set of URL strings saved in my database
e.g. `file:///storage/sdcard0/folder/folder/folder/Image.jpg`

Right Now I have this in **Activity A**:

```
public class LoadMainMenuActivty  extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String TEST_FILE_NAME = "Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new Constants(this.getBaseContext());


        setContentView(R.layout.load_main_menu_activity);

        File testImageOnSdCard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEST_FILE_NAME);
        if (!testImageOnSdCard.exists()) {
            copyTestImageToSdCard(testImageOnSdCard);
        }

        new createFolders().execute();
        // Initialize Buttons
        Button btnOrderByList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOrder);



        // Button Start Application
        // btnStartApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartApp);
        btnOrderByList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Perform action on click
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoadMainGroupsActivty.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    public void onImageGridClick(View view) {
        Log.d("Error", "Here");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, IMAGES);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        imageLoader.stop();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void copyTestImageToSdCard(final File testImageOnSdCard) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputStream is = getAssets().open(TEST_FILE_NAME);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testImageOnSdCard);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int read;
                    try {
                        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    L.w("Can't copy test image onto SD card");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class createFolders extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Creating folders in SD card


        }

    }

}
```

in **Constants Class**:

```
public final class Constants {

    static DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
    static Context context;

    public Constants(Context context)
    {
        Constants.context = context;
    }

    static Context getContext()
    {
        return Constants.context;

    }

    ///public static final List<String> IMAGES = db.getImagePath();
    //Not sure with this

    static String[] paths = db.getImagePath();
    public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
            // Heavy images
            "file:///storage/sdcard0/folder/folder/folder/image.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-K2FMuOozxU0/T3R4lRAiBTI/AAAAAAAAAE8/a3Eh9JvnnzI/s1024/sample_image_02.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-SCS5C646rxM/T3R4l7QB6xI/AAAAAAAAAFE/xLcuVv3CUyA/s1024/sample_image_03.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-f0NJR6-_Thg/T3R4mNex2wI/AAAAAAAAAFI/45oug4VE8MI/s1024/sample_image_04.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-n-xcJmiI0pg/T3R4mkSchHI/AAAAAAAAAFU/EoiNNb7kk3A/s1024/sample_image_05.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-X43vAudm7f4/T3R4nGSChJI/AAAAAAAAAFk/3bna6D-2EE8/s1024/sample_image_06.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-MpZneqIyjXU/T3R4nuGO1aI/AAAAAAAAAFg/r09OPjLx1ZY/s1024/sample_image_07.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ql3YNfdClJo/T3XvW9apmFI/AAAAAAAAAL4/_6HFDzbahc4/s1024/sample_image_08.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Pxa7eqF4cyc/T3R4oasvPEI/AAAAAAAAAF0/-uYDH92h8LA/s1024/sample_image_09.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Li-rjhFEuaI/T3R4o-VUl4I/AAAAAAAAAF8/5E5XdMnP1oE/s1024/sample_image_10.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_HU4fImgFhA/T3R4pPVIwWI/AAAAAAAAAGA/0RfK_Vkgth4/s1024/sample_image_11.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0gnNrVjwa0Y/T3R4peGYJwI/AAAAAAAAAGU/uX_9wvRPM9I/s1024/sample_image_12.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HBxuzALS_Zs/T3R4qERykaI/AAAAAAAAAGQ/_qQ16FaZ1q0/s1024/sample_image_13.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cKojDrARNjQ/T3R4qfWSGPI/AAAAAAAAAGY/MR5dnbNaPyY/s1024/sample_image_14.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-WujkdYfcyZ8/T3R4qrIMGUI/AAAAAAAAAGk/277LIdgvnjg/s1024/sample_image_15.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-FMHR7Vy3PgI/T3R4rOXlEKI/AAAAAAAAAGs/VeXrDNDBkaw/s1024/sample_image_16.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-mrR0AJyNTH0/T3R4rZs6CuI/AAAAAAAAAG0/UE1wQqCOqLA/s1024/sample_image_17.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-z77w0eh3cow/T3R4rnLn05I/AAAAAAAAAG4/BaerfWoNucU/s1024/sample_image_18.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-aWVwh1OU5Bk/T3R4sAWw0yI/AAAAAAAAAHE/4_KAvJttFwA/s1024/sample_image_19.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-q-js52DMnWQ/T3R4tZhY2sI/AAAAAAAAAHM/A8kjp2Ivdqg/s1024/sample_image_20.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_jIzvvzXKn4/T3R4t7xpdVI/AAAAAAAAAHU/7QC6eZ10jgs/s1024/sample_image_21.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lnGi4IMLpwU/T3R4uCMa7vI/AAAAAAAAAHc/1zgzzz6qTpk/s1024/sample_image_22.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-fFCzKjFPsPc/T3R4u0SZPFI/AAAAAAAAAHk/sbgjzrktOK0/s1024/sample_image_23.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-8TqoW5gBE_Y/T3R4vBS3NPI/AAAAAAAAAHs/EZYvpNsaNXk/s1024/sample_image_24.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-gc4eQ3ySdzs/T3R4vafoA7I/AAAAAAAAAH4/yKii5P6tqDE/s1024/sample_image_25.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--NYOPCylU7Q/T3R4vjAiWkI/AAAAAAAAAH8/IPNx5q3ptRA/s1024/sample_image_26.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-9IJM8so4vCI/T3R4vwJO2yI/AAAAAAAAAIE/ljlr-cwuqZM/s1024/sample_image_27.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KW6QwOHfhBs/T3R4w0RsQiI/AAAAAAAAAIM/uEFLVgHPFCk/s1024/sample_image_28.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-z2557Ec1ctY/T3R4x3QA2hI/AAAAAAAAAIk/9-GzPL1lTWE/s1024/sample_image_29.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-LaKXAn4Kr1c/T3R4yc5b4lI/AAAAAAAAAIY/fMgcOVQfmD0/s1024/sample_image_30.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-F9LRToJoQdo/T3R4yrLtyQI/AAAAAAAAAIg/ri9uUCWuRmo/s1024/sample_image_31.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-6X-xBwP-QpI/T3R4zGVboII/AAAAAAAAAIs/zYH4PjjngY0/s1024/sample_image_32.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-VdLRjbW4LAs/T3R4zXu3gUI/AAAAAAAAAIw/9aFp9t7mCPg/s1024/sample_image_33.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-gL6R17_fDJU/T3R4zpIXGjI/AAAAAAAAAI8/Q2Vjx-L9X20/s1024/sample_image_34.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1fGH4YJXEzo/T3R40Y1B7KI/AAAAAAAAAJE/MnTsa77g-nk/s1024/sample_image_35.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Ql0jHSrea-A/T3R403mUfFI/AAAAAAAAAJM/qzI4SkcH9tY/s1024/sample_image_36.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-BL5FIBR_tzI/T3R41DA0AKI/AAAAAAAAAJk/GZfeeb-SLM0/s1024/sample_image_37.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-wF2Vc9YDutw/T3R41fR2BCI/AAAAAAAAAJc/JdU1sHdMRAk/s1024/sample_image_38.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ZWHiPehwjTI/T3R41zuaKCI/AAAAAAAAAJg/hR3QJ1v3REg/s1024/sample_image_39.jpg",
            // Light images
            "http://tabletpcssource.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/android-logo.png",
            "http://simpozia.com/pages/images/stories/windows-icon.png",
            "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1135218951/gmail_profile_icon3_normal.png",
            "http://www.krify.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Macromedia_Flash_dock_icon.png",
            "http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/radio.png",
            "http://www.bandwidthblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/twitter-logo.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100907_itunes1.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100929_applications.png",
            "http://www.idyllicmusic.com/index_files/get_apple-iphone.png",
            "http://www.frenchrevolutionfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/Twitter-Bird.png",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ka5MiRGJ_S4/TdD9OoF6bmI/AAAAAAAAE8k/7ydKtptUtSg/s1600/Google_Sky%2BMaps_Android.png",
            "http://www.desiredsoft.com/images/icon_webhosting.png",
            "http://goodereader.com/apps/wp-content/uploads/downloads/thumbnails/2012/01/hi-256-0-99dda8c730196ab93c67f0659d5b8489abdeb977.png",
            "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mlaJ4p_3rBU/TdD9OWxN8II/AAAAAAAAE8U/xyynWwr3_4Q/s1600/antivitus_free.png",
            "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transformers/computer.png",
            "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/firefox.png?7794fe",
            "https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.rovio.angrybirdsseasons/hi-256-9-347dae230614238a639d21508ae492302340b2ba",
            "http://androidblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/tablet-pc-256x256.jpg",
            "http://www.theblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Apple.png",
            "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y-HQwQ4Kuu0/TdD9_iKIY7I/AAAAAAAAE88/3G4xiclDZD0/s1600/Twitter_Android.png",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nAf4IMJGpc8/TdD9OGNUHHI/AAAAAAAAE8E/VM9yU_lIgZ4/s1600/Adobe%2BReader_Android.png",
            "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/oovoo-android.png?7794fe",
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kocco/ndroid/128/android-market-2-icon.png",
            "http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png",
            "http://c.wrzuta.pl/wm16596/a32f1a47002ab3a949afeb4f",
            "http://macprovid.vo.llnwd.net/o43/hub/media/1090/6882/01_headline_Muse.jpg",
            // Special cases
            "http://cdn.urbanislandz.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/MMSposter-large.jpg", // very large image
            "file:///sdcard/Universal Image Loader @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.png", // Image from SD card with encoded symbols
            "assets://Living Things @#&=+-_.,!()~'%20.jpg", // Image from assets
            "drawable://" + R.drawable.ic_launcher, // Image from drawables
            "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/b/b6/ÐšÐ°Ðº_ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚_Ñ?_Ð¼Ñ‹ÑˆÐ°Ð¼Ð¸_Ð²Ð¾ÐµÐ²Ð°Ð».png", // Link with UTF-8
            "https://www.eff.org/sites/default/files/chrome150_0.jpg", // Image from HTTPS
            "http://bit.ly/soBiXr", // Redirect link
            "http://img001.us.expono.com/100001/100001-1bc30-2d736f_m.jpg", // EXIF
            "", // Empty link
            "http://wrong.site.com/corruptedLink", // Wrong link
    };



    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    public static class Extra {
        public static final String IMAGES = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGES";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }
}
```

**ImageGridActivity:**

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends AbsListViewBaseActivity {

    String[] imageUrls;

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

        listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImagePagerActivity(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
    public String[] getImagePath()
    {
        String [] paths = null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PATH;



        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        int i = 1;
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                paths[i] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
                Log.d("getPathImage:", cursor.getString(0).toString());
                i++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

         return paths;



    }
```

Honestly, I have no idea on how or where will I assign the images returned from the database into `IMAGES`

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
"file:///storage/sdcard0/folder/folder/folder/Image.jpg",};
```

Comment: The strange is: why there is a static final variable with a dynamic value?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure as well, any clear suggest would really help sir, Thanks for interacting.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<String> getImagePath()
{
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PATH;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            paths.add(cursor.getString(0).toString());
            Log.d("getPathImage:", cursor.getString(0).toString());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

     return paths;
}
```

Then

```
      DBHandler db = new DBHandler(ActivityName.this);
      db.open();
      ArrayList<String> list = getImagePath();
```

Now you can use the list in your adapter class and use the same to displays images using Universal Image loader.

A side note you can get the path of images from sdcard and display images using UIL. So you don't need database for this purpose.

Bit more of how to use UIL.

After getting the paths

```
    ListView lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(ActivityName.this,list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

LazyAdaper

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList path;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
DisplayImageOptions options;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> paths) {
    activity = a;
    path = paths;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "MyFolderCache");


 // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
   imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
              // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
             .discCacheExtraOptions(1024, 1024, CompressFormat.PNG, 100)
             .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
             .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
             .enableLogging()
             .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
    //imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(a));
   // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
    .build();
}



public int getCount() {
    return path.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();;
    if(convertView==null)
    {

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);   
    vh.iv=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivv); 
    vh.pb= (ProgressBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.pb); 
    vh.tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    vh.tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }
    vh.tv.setText("Image in postion =");
    vh.tv1.setText(""+position);
    display(vh.iv, data[position], vh.pb);
    //imageLoader.displayImage(path.get(position).toString(), image,options);

    return vi;
}

public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
{
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}
 public static class ViewHolder
 {
  ImageView iv;
  TextView tv,tv1;
  ProgressBar pb;

 }
}
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
     android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:text="TextView" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

You check an example of UIL @
[Caching images and displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285)

To get the images from sdcard consider your folder contains images.

```
private File[] listFile;
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();

public void getFromSdcard()
{
    File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyFolder");

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
             for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
            {
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }   

        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!! https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/HomeActivity.java - I am getting error from this onImageGridClick: "The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)"

Comment: @lordzden its confusing. What are you trying to do. Edit your question and post some code also add some more escription

Comment: @lordzden you don't need constants.java since you have the list of paths. You want to display images in sdcard using UIL?

Comment: yes I want to display the images from SD card using UIL, thou I will be using the SD card path(Strings) to access them not planting it, with out overhauling the codes. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @lordzden you can get the path of images store it in an arraylist and then display the same. Check the edit to get the list of paths from sdcard. I don't know what you require and looks like you are getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `if` clause in `DatabaseHandler` after `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);` as below:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add(cursor.getString(0).toString());
 cursor.moveToNext();
 }
 String[] paths = list.toArray(new String[list .size()]);
 return paths;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this :

```
String [] paths = null;
```

and then this :

```
paths[i] = cursor.getString(0).toString(); // i is 0 initially
```

This will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can use a `List<String>` for this purpose instead of `String[]` . Add each element to the `List<String>` using its `add()` method.

```
List<String> pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
pathList.add(cursor.getString(0));
```

Then return an array from the method as :

```
return pathList.toArray(new String[pathList.size()]);
```

Comment: I am getting force close, I am worried coz even is if I use ArrayList<String>, without the proper flow I can't do the right thing. Also, in my Constant Class it's messed up. Can you bit show me the relationship of each classes where I can insert ArrayList<String>? thanks for the prompt answer!