# DiskLruCache from android tutorial is missing lots of methods.

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-image, diskspace

Here is the disk cache tutorial I'm following. I've downloaded the source code to DiskLruCache but none of the methods used in this example exist in the source code.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache

Do I need to implement these methods myself or is there a version of DiskLruCache that I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=29400&aid=294000000000&name=DiskLruCache.java&token=Rstp2OFViiWaUGS68yFfFgMQDEk%3A1335231242264

Comment: Have you found the correct DiskLruCache.java ? Maybe this can work: https://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/DiskLruCache.html

Comment: [issuetracker.google.com/issues/37002468](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37002468)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete implementation of `DiskLruCache`.

First download [DiskLruCache.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/DiskLruCache.java) from AOSP.

Here is my `DiskCache.java` a helper class for basic cache operations.

```
/**
 * Created by Babar on 12-Aug-15.
 */
public class DiskCache
{

    private Context context;

    private static DiskCache diskCache;

    public DiskLruCache mDiskLruCache;

    private final Object mDiskCacheLock = new Object();

    private BitmapProcessor bitmapProcessor;

    private static final int DISK_CACHE_INDEX = 0;

    public static boolean mDiskCacheStarting = true;

    private static final String DISK_CACHE_SUBDIR = "ooredoo_thumbnails";

    private static final int DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100MB

    public static DiskCache getInstance()
    {
        if(diskCache == null)
        {
            diskCache = new DiskCache();
        }

        return diskCache;
    }

    private DiskCache() {}

    public void requestInit(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;

        bitmapProcessor = new BitmapProcessor();

        new DiskCacheTask(this).execute(DiskCacheTask.INIT);
    }

    public void init() throws IOException {
        synchronized (mDiskCacheLock)
        {
            if(mDiskLruCache == null || mDiskLruCache.isClosed())
            {
                File cacheDir = FileUtils.getDiskCacheDir(context, DISK_CACHE_SUBDIR);

                if(!cacheDir.exists())
                {
                    cacheDir.mkdir();
                }

                if(FileUtils.getUsableSpace(cacheDir) > DISK_CACHE_SIZE)
                {
                    mDiskLruCache = DiskLruCache.open(cacheDir, 1, 1, DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.print("InitDiskCache failed: NOT enough space on disk");
                }
            }

            mDiskCacheStarting = false; // Finished initialization
            mDiskCacheLock.notifyAll(); // Wake any waiting threads
        }
    }


    public void addBitmapToDiskCache(final String key, final Bitmap value) {
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            return;
        }

        synchronized (mDiskCacheLock)
        {
            if (mDiskLruCache != null) {
                OutputStream out = null;

                String encryptedKey = CryptoUtils.encryptToMD5(key);

                Logger.print("addBitmapToDiskCache encryptToMD5: " + encryptedKey);

                try {
                    DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = mDiskLruCache.get(encryptedKey);

                    if (snapshot == null) {
                        final DiskLruCache.Editor editor = mDiskLruCache.edit(encryptedKey);

                        if (editor != null) {
                            out = editor.newOutputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX);

                            value.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

                            editor.commit();
                            out.close();
                        }
                    } else {
                        snapshot.getInputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX).close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (out != null) {
                        try {
                            out.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get from disk cache.
     *
     * @param key Unique identifier for which item to get
     * @return The bitmap if found in cache, null otherwise
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromDiskCache(final String key)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        String encryptedKey = CryptoUtils.encryptToMD5(key);

        Logger.print("getBitmapFromDiskCache encryptToMD5: " + encryptedKey);

        synchronized (mDiskCacheLock)
        {
            Logger.print("mDiskcachestarting: "+mDiskCacheStarting);
            // Wait while disk cache is started from background thread
            while (mDiskCacheStarting)
            {
                try
                {
                    mDiskCacheLock.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(mDiskLruCache != null)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = null;

                try
                {
                    final DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = mDiskLruCache.get(encryptedKey);

                    if(snapshot != null)
                    {
                        Logger.print("Disk cache hit");

                        inputStream = snapshot.getInputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX);

                        if(inputStream != null)
                        {
                            FileDescriptor fd = ((FileInputStream) inputStream).getFD();

                            // Decode bitmap, but we don't want to sample so give
                            // MAX_VALUE as the target dimensions

                            bitmap = bitmapProcessor.decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(fd);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(inputStream != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Logger.print("dCache getBitmapFromDiskCache synchronized completed");
        }

        Logger.print("dCache getBitmapFromDiskCache returning Bitmap");
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void requestFlush()
    {
        new DiskCacheTask(this).execute(DiskCacheTask.FLUSH);
    }

    /**
     * Flushes the disk cache associated with this ImageCache object. Note that this includes
     * disk access so this should not be executed on the main/UI thread.
     */
    public void flush()
    {
        synchronized (mDiskCacheLock)
        {
            if(mDiskLruCache != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    mDiskLruCache.flush();

                    Logger.print("flush: disk cache flushed");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void requestClose()
    {
        new DiskCacheTask(this).execute(DiskCacheTask.CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * Closes the disk cache associated with this ImageCache object. Note that this includes
     * disk access so this should not be executed on the main/UI thread.
     */
    public void close()
    {
        synchronized (mDiskCacheLock)
        {
            if(mDiskLruCache != null)
            {
                if(!mDiskLruCache.isClosed())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mDiskLruCache.close();
                        mDiskLruCache = null;

                        Logger.print("disk cache closed");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Do not call this method unless you need to explicitly clear disk cache
     */
    public void requestTearDown()
    {
        new DiskCacheTask(this).execute(DiskCacheTask.TEAR_DOWN);
    }

    public final void tearDown()
    {
        synchronized (mDiskCacheLock)
        {
            mDiskCacheStarting = true;

            if(mDiskLruCache != null && !mDiskLruCache.isClosed())
            {
                try
                {
                    mDiskLruCache.delete();

                    Logger.print("disk cache cleared");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mDiskLruCache = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `BitmapProcesser.java`

```
/**
 * @author  Babar
 * @since 15-Jun-15.
 */
public class BitmapProcessor
{
    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(InputStream inputStream, URL url,
                                                int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

        int width = options.outWidth;
        int height = options.outHeight;

        Logger.print("@Req Width: "+reqWidth);
        Logger.print("@Req Height: " + reqHeight);

        Logger.print("@Actual Width: "+width);
        Logger.print("@Actual Height: " + height);

        int sampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

        inputStream = url.openStream();

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

        if(bitmap != null)
        {
            width = bitmap.getWidth();
            height = bitmap.getHeight();

            Logger.print("@inSample:"+sampleSize);
            Logger.print("@Modified Width: "+width);
            Logger.print("@Modified Height: " + height);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(FileDescriptor fd)
    {
        /*final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;*/

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);

    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String pathName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        int width = options.outWidth;
        int height = options.outHeight;

        Logger.print("@Req Width: "+reqWidth);
        Logger.print("@Req Height: " + reqHeight);

        Logger.print("@Actual Width: "+width);
        Logger.print("@Actual Height: " + height);

        int sampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        if(bitmap != null)
        {
            width = bitmap.getWidth();
            height = bitmap.getHeight();

            Logger.print("@inSample:"+sampleSize);
            Logger.print("@Modified Width: "+width);
            Logger.print("@Modified Height: " + height);
        }

        return bitmap != null ? rotateBitmapIfNeeded(pathName, bitmap) : null;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                     int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight)
    {
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        final int height = options.outHeight;

        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if(width > requiredWidth || height > requiredHeight)
        {
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfWidth / inSampleSize) > requiredWidth
                                    &&
                    (halfHeight / inSampleSize) > requiredHeight)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateBitmapIfNeeded(String pathName, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(pathName);

        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        Logger.logI("BITMAP_ORIENTATION: " + orientation, pathName);

        switch (orientation)
        {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:

                return rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

                return rotateBitmap(bitmap, 180);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

                return rotateBitmap(bitmap, 270);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap makeBitmapRound(Bitmap src)
    {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

       // Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(src, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(shader);



        RectF rectF = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);

        // rect contains the bounds of the shape
        // radius is the radius in pixels of the rounded corners
        // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(src);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, 30, 30, paint);

        return src;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
}
```

Here is `CryptoUtils.java`

```
/**
 * @author Babar
 * @since 29-Jun-15.
 */
public class CryptoUtils
{
    private static final String MD5_ALGO = "MD5";


    public static String encryptToMD5(String text)
    {
        try
        {
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MD5_ALGO);
            md.update(text.getBytes());

            byte[] bytes = md.digest();

            String hex = bytesToHexString(bytes);

            return hex;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return String.valueOf(text.hashCode());
        }
    }

    private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);

            if(hex.length() == 1)
            {
                sb.append('0');
            }

            sb.append(hex);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String encodeToBase64(String str) {
        String tmp = "";
        if(isNotNullOrEmpty(str)) {
            try {
                tmp = new String(Base64.encode(str.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)).trim();
            } catch(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Here is `DiskCacheTask.java`

```
/**
 * Created by Babar on 12-Aug-15.
 */
public class DiskCacheTask extends BaseAsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>
{
    private DiskCache diskCache;

    public static final int INIT = 1;

    public static final int FLUSH = 2;

    public static final int CLOSE = 3;

    public static final int TEAR_DOWN = 4;

    public static final int REMOVE = 5;

    public DiskCacheTask(DiskCache diskCache)
    {
        this.diskCache = diskCache;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        switch (params[0])
        {
            case INIT:

                try
                {
                    diskCache.init();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;

            case FLUSH:

                diskCache.flush();

                break;

            case CLOSE:

                diskCache.close();

                break;

            case TEAR_DOWN:

                diskCache.tearDown();

                break;

            case REMOVE:

                diskCache.remove();

                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

To initialize the cache simply call `new DiskCache().getInstance().requestInit();` ideally from your MainActivity's `onCreate()`. Also note Disk operation should be done in separate thread for example `Handler` , `AsyncTask`. So when ever you want to add/get bitmap to/from disk cache do this from a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap the DiskLruCache with your own cache that offers higher level abstractions. Someone has already done this for bitmaps, see [Using DiskLruCache in android 4.0 does not provide for openCache method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185898/using-disklrucache-in-android-4-0-does-not-provide-for-opencache-method)

Alternatively, you can use an open source library such as Picasso.