# Load image from URL to imageView as well as Cache

Tags: android, caching, imageview

Hi i am new beginner in android. I want to insert image in imageView from URL but whenever one time it is loaded from URL in imageView then second time it should be insert without internet means it would be stored in cache as well.

Comment: so what have you done so far ?

Comment: use fresco, it is image loading library of facebook and seems good to me https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Comment: Checkout this if you are looking for diskcache http://stackoverflow.com/a/32516598/1939564 and this if you are looking for memory cache http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for this you can use picasso Library
You can download it from Picasso Library site simply put this jar file into libs folder. It will manage all property of Image. 
  http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
String imgURL = "Your URL";
ivmage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgURL).into(ivmage);
```

Comment: thanx third party is best way

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Picasso` Library.

By Using `Picasso`, The Advantages are

- Handling **ImageView recycling** and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
- **Automatic memory and disk caching**.

To load `Image` from `Url`

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Refer this link for Api : [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
Glide.with(this).load("imageURl").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest picasso library for doing this. [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is the detailed documentation of picasso library.

ex:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

or you can make use of volley's ImageLoader. [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) you can find the documentation for Volley's image loading.

ex :

```
// Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }, 0, 0, null,
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
        }
    });
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

if you are using volley. then you have to cache images manually. picasso will cache images by default.