# Loading images into Listview using Lazyloading Getting Error

Tags: android

I am new to android and i have a problem in loading images to listview.I am using lazy loading for image loading, the problem is that when we load more than 40 images there will be a `org.eclipse.jdi:timeout exception`. How can we solve the issue.

Here is my code

```
 private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating json parser class
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed countries list
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

            try{
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }          

            // Keys used in Hashmap 
            String[] from = { "username","flag","details"};

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.tv_country,R.id.iv_flag,R.id.tv_user};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);  

            return adapter;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {


            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);


                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }
        }       
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {
            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);


                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.connect();

                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();


                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");               

                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

                if(b!=null)
                {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              


                fOutStream.flush();

                fOutStream.close();             

                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());
                                                hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

                 return hmBitmap;               
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

This is my logcat

```
10-15 16:14:07.573: I/dalvikvm(268): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
10-15 16:14:07.573: I/AndroidRuntime(268): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-15 16:14:08.202: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x34dd50:0x34de5c] in 429794 ns
10-15 16:14:08.532: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 865 objects / 62936 bytes in 70ms
10-15 16:14:09.382: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.example./.MainActivity: 1907 ms (total 1907 ms)
10-15 16:14:13.232: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.example./.Loginclass }
10-15 16:14:13.822: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.example./.Loginclass: 580 ms (total 580 ms)
10-15 16:14:16.261: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.example./.search.Search }
10-15 16:14:16.772: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x356bc0:0x356c7c] in 378809 ns
10-15 16:14:17.011: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4701 objects / 245664 bytes in 282ms
10-15 16:14:18.242: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.example./.search.Search: 1954 ms (total 1954 ms)
10-15 16:14:26.783: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.example./.searchresult.SearchResult (has extras) }
10-15 16:14:27.082: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12519 objects / 739728 bytes in 101ms
10-15 16:14:27.082: I/dalvikvm-heap(275): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.747MB for 87396-byte allocation
10-15 16:14:27.242: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.example./.searchresult.SearchResult: 421 ms (total 421 ms)
10-15 16:14:27.312: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 317 objects / 13368 bytes in 234ms
10-15 16:14:27.362: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 52ms
10-15 16:14:27.362: I/dalvikvm-heap(275): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.817MB for 87396-byte allocation
10-15 16:14:27.422: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 59ms
10-15 16:14:32.465: D/Exception while downloading url(275): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
10-15 16:14:32.465: D/Background Task(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 16:14:32.482: D/JSON Exception1(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 16:14:32.482: D/Exception(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 16:14:32.492: D/AndroidRuntime(275): Shutting down VM
10-15 16:14:32.492: W/dalvikvm(275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:436)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example..searchresult.SearchResult$ListViewLoaderTask.onPostExecute(SearchResult.java:236)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example..searchresult.SearchResult$ListViewLoaderTask.onPostExecute(SearchResult.java:1)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-15 16:14:32.502: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:14:32.522: W/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.example./.searchresult.SearchResult
10-15 16:14:33.042: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{46060820 com.example./.searchresult.SearchResult}
10-15 16:14:42.548: W/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-15 16:14:43.092: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4601a300 com.example./.search.Search}
10-15 16:14:48.333: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{46060820 com.example./.searchresult.SearchResult}
10-15 16:14:48.962: I/Process(275): Sending signal. PID: 275 SIG: 9
10-15 16:14:49.002: I/ActivityManager(58): Process com.example. (pid 275) has died.
10-15 16:14:49.042: I/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{45fc9600 com.example./com.example..Loginclass paused=false}
10-15 16:14:49.042: I/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{461154c0 com.example./com.example..searchresult.SearchResult paused=false}
10-15 16:14:49.042: I/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{46113e10 com.example./com.example..search.Search paused=false}
10-15 16:14:49.072: I/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.example. for activity com.example./.Loginclass: pid=290 uid=10037 gids={3003}
10-15 16:14:49.132: W/Process(58): Unable to open /proc/275/status
10-15 16:14:49.322: I/UsageStats(58): Unexpected resume of com.example. while already resumed in com.example.
10-15 16:14:49.552: W/InputManagerService(58): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 275 uid 10037
10-15 16:14:50.022: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.example./.Loginclass: 1009 ms (total 1009 ms)
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the URLs not responding...

Comment: Lazy Loading using Universal Image Loader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying

Comment: Why dont you use the universalimageloader lib ? for lazy loading of images ?

Comment: @JoxTraex But i get the images when i reduced the image count

Comment: @DharaShah I am new to android,i don't know what are the libraries for image loading. My friend suggested this method.

Comment: @Deepu https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader , the library, import this in your project and then follow the steps given by them

Answer (score 2):

Try Lazy Loading,

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

this is very simple example on Lazy Loading for listView.

hope this will help you.

Comment: On this code they use static values, i need to get the values from a url

Comment: @Deepu You have Url. String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
so use this imgUrl  in imageLoader.DisplayImage(imgUrl , image);