# Is there a way to use universal image loader to download (and cache) non image files

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I want to use the `uil` current download infrastructure (and caching) to get files from internet **that are not images**.

Is there a way to achieve that? Or classes I should look into?

Note: here are the current very image oriented `uil` downloaders:

```
ImageDownloader
|---- BaseImageDownloader
|      |---- HttpClientImageDownloader
|---- NetworkDeniedImageDownloader
|---- SlowNetworkImageDownloader
```

Comment: take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying

Comment: Have you looked the documentation of Universal Image Loader? If not see that. It will reply to your all answer

Comment: I updated the question, adding details