# How to use asynctask to load images thumbnail in android

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, imageview, bitmapimage

I am trying to get thumbnail of more then 10 videos from server to Image-view in android. Now i am successfully able to display thumbnail's of videos into image-view but my problem is it is taking too much time to display all thumbnail's. So it is showing blank black screen till it load all thumbnail's.

So i decided to use Asynctask that show's progress bar till it load's all thumbnail's but it doesn't show progress bar at all. So any idea how to solve this issue.

**Code**

```
ImageView video_one, video_two, video_three, video_four, video_five;
ImageView video_six, video_seven, video_eight, video_nine, video_ten;
ImageView video_ele, video_twe, video_thir, video_fort, video_fif;

    String path  = "http://serverlink/Fidol/upload/test.mp4";
    String path1 = "http://serverlink/Fidol/upload/ABCD.mp4";
    String path2 = "http://serverlink/Fidol/upload/bean.mp4";
    String path3 = "http://serverlink/Fidol/upload/masti.mp4";
    String path4 = "http://serverlink/Fidol/upload/ben.mp4";

        Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    Bitmap bm1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path1,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    Bitmap bm2 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path2,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    Bitmap bm3 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path3,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    Bitmap bm4 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path4,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

then i have called

```
new loadThumbnail().execute();
```

and here is my asynctask class

```
class loadThumbnail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowVideo.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Videos... Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            video_one.setImageBitmap(bm);
            video_two.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            video_three.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            video_four.setImageBitmap(bm3);
            video_five.setImageBitmap(bm4);

            video_six.setImageBitmap(bm);
            video_seven.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            video_eight.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            video_nine.setImageBitmap(bm3);
            video_ten.setImageBitmap(bm4);

            video_ele.setImageBitmap(bm);
            video_twe.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            video_thir.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            video_fort.setImageBitmap(bm3);
            video_fif.setImageBitmap(bm4);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use lazy loading with UIL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying

Comment: @Raghunandan, Thank you, but i don't have list-view as well as any custom class in this case how can i use your answer please help. I just have few image-view in which i want to show video thumbnail and till it load it should show progressbar. that's it.

Comment: you can't update ui from backgroudn thread you are setting bitmap in doinbackground which is not possible. I think it is better you use a listview. There in the link you get images from server here you get it from mediastore

Comment: @Raghunandan, can i use gridview instead of listview???

Comment: yes you can use gridview which works similar to listview

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try with grid-view and let you know.

Comment: doInBackground basically runs on a background thread. You should not modifying views in threads other than UI thread.

Comment: @Pavan, Sorry but i didn't get what you are trying to say, can you explain...

Comment: @Raghunandan, Thank you for this great example, +1 for this, I have upvoted your answer over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this :

```
            video_one.setImageBitmap(bm);
            video_two.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            video_three.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            video_four.setImageBitmap(bm3);
            video_five.setImageBitmap(bm4);

            video_six.setImageBitmap(bm);
            video_seven.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            video_eight.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            video_nine.setImageBitmap(bm3);
            video_ten.setImageBitmap(bm4);

            video_ele.setImageBitmap(bm);
            video_twe.setImageBitmap(bm1);
            video_thir.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            video_fort.setImageBitmap(bm3);
            video_fif.setImageBitmap(bm4);
```

in onPostExecute becuase you can not modify ui from doinbackground

and do this in doInbackground

```
        Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        Bitmap bm1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path1,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        Bitmap bm2 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path2,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        Bitmap bm3 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path3,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        Bitmap bm4 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path4,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put

```
Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
Bitmap bm1 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path1,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
Bitmap bm2 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path2,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
Bitmap bm3 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path3,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
Bitmap bm4 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path4,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

under the `doInBackground` method because as far as I understand thats where the task is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In AsyncTask there's a method call`onProgressUpdate(Integer...)` which you can make use for progress updating.
[Check this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowVideo.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Videos... Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

Also in your code if you have written `loadThumbnail.get()` somewhere remove that too,as this will block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
class SetThumb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
private ImageView imageView;
SetThumb(ImageView imageView){
    this.imageView=imageView;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
    return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(strings[0],MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap thumb){
    imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
}
```

}

**NOW EXECUTE THIS TASK**

```
new SetThumb(your_image_view).execute(path_of_file);
```