# Java/Android - ListView (optimization) when I load many images

Tags: java, android, listview, optimization

i have project when i use listview and in this listview has a Image, naturally, these images will be downloaded, and the problem is that if a person does not wi-fi through, the traffic just quickly go away. How do I make the images weighed less?

I can download in two ways.

First:

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.image, URL);
```

Second:

```
Picasso.with(ctx)
            .load(URL)
            .resize(800, 800)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.image);
```

I think, need to download image in low quality, but i dont know, which library so can

Comment: using UIL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying

Comment: maybe exist other options?