# Image from URL using SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, json, image

I am using this code to get data from JSON.

```
public class ShowContacts extends ListActivity{

    private static String url = "http://192.168.0.103/contacts.json";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

    JSONArray contacts = null;

    int index = 0;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.showjson);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new GetContacts().execute();

    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();           
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);

                        contactList.add(contact);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            String[] from = { TAG_NAME, TAG_IMAGE };

            int[] to = { R.id.name, R.id.image };

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

                ShowContacts.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, from , to );        

            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }

}
```

I want to get the name and image from JSON. I am getting the name and it is displaying on the list, but I can't get the image. This is my JSON:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "image": "http://192.168.0.103/image1.png"
        },
        {                 
            "name": "John Wayne",
            "image": "http://192.168.0.103/image2.png"
        }    
    ]
}
```

I think it is not working because the image is online and the it tries to add it as `Drawable`. I am not sure how to do this. Is there any way?

Comment: have a look at this: http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/ or this http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader you have to load the image from that url

Comment: try this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to download the image using the LazyLoading and load that into the `ImageView`. You can not directly load the image just simply parsing and  setting url into `ImageView`.

Use the Concept of [LazyLoading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) or [Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Check the simple demostration of [Loading Image from URL](http://sam-androidhelp.blogspot.in/2012/01/lazy-loading-in-android.html)

Comment: Can you please edit a little bit my code. I am new to Android.

Comment: @Enve You can not download and set image using `SimpleAdapter` class. You have to implement the `BaseAdapter` for that and in your adapter class you can load your image using LazyLoading. Check out last link of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1)you can use **Universal ImageLoader** to download image from specific URL and Disply in to your List.

you do not use direct imageURL to show it in list item

please check this universal image loader [reference link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

public class ItemImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> contactList;
private ImageLoader iml;

public ItemImagesAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> image_paths) {
    context = ctx;
    contactList = image_paths;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activity).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    iml = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_image, parent, false);
    }
    String imagepath = contactList.get(position).getImagePaths();
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(contactlist.get(position).getText);
    iml.displayImage(imagepath, image);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

inside onPostExecute()

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ItemImagesAdapter adapter = new ItemImagesAdapter(getAppicationContext(), contactlist);
        listViewobj.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

call this from you mainactivity. i hope you know how to set to adapter..
hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

One and the best method for downloading images from server is [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/). you can download  upto 5k images without any memory error.

**Download** Android query jar from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.24.3.jar) and put in libs folder of your project.

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(_scontext); // Android query object
ImageView _imageObject= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image); // your imageview onbject
```

// and using below code you can set the image in imageview.

```
aq.id(_imageObject).image("image url as string");
```