# What is the best way to save images in Parse?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

What am I trying to achieve: Based on some filters by the app user, I want to return a list with text and images.

How am I doing it: I have created a table in Parse and have added a column with object type as 'file'. I have put all the jpg/gif images into that column. (double-click, browse, select image from local computer).

The trouble I am having is, the list takes considerable time (~7 seconds) before it is displayed on my android app.

Is there a better way of handling image data within Parse or should I store images somewhere else (like Amazon S3)?

I am using standard queries for Parse in order to get data, nevertheless, am also checking if there is any code latency. Wanted to confirm if I am correctly handling the image data for back-end or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of handling image data within Parse or should I
>   store images somewhere else (like Amazon S3)?

If your images is not too much or you are using for example(five image) its better to save the into the `Assets` or `Drawable` Folder for loading.
and if i correctly knows about this problem, you need to use `ProgressBar` and one image, before loading the Images in `Internet`.

[Caching images and displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Parse to store images too, but it's not slow as you said. Since Parse is part of Facebook, I think their infrastructure is the same. There are possible issues:

- Internet connection: Slow or on 3G?
- Images: files are big?

Let me know which case you are in.

If you just display thumbnail images, I suggest you to process it before saving to Parse by writing Cloud function as describe on [their blog](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/new-cloud-modules-for-images-and-users/). The you just need to use generated thumbnails on your listview/gridview